# Set value of checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to set the value of a checkbox using javascript?

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("form1").getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work because `getElementsByTagName` returns an Array-like collection. You need to access members of the collection by index, like `[0]`. ...oh, also, there's no `checkbox` tag name.

Comment: Do you want to use jquery ? Otherwise will you use only javascript ?

Comment: I would suggest a different name than 'checkbox' for your input.

Comment: Why do you have the jQuery tag if you're not using jQuery's API in the question?

Comment: @user1689607 both will work If you suggest the solution with jquery as well as with javscript.

Comment: Basically, I am getting the checkbox value through request object in node.js and there I am getting null/undefined. Now anybody can help me?

Code:
logger.info("checkbox value is: ",request.param('checkbox'));

output:
checkbox value is:  ''

login.ejs
function changeValue() {
var checkbox = document.forms["form1"].checkbox.value = "your value here";
}
<form id="form1" method="post" action="/login">
     
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="" /> Remember me<br />
     
</form>

Comment: @Christoph why downvote? I did not know about this thats why I asked this question. It is a public forum you should not do so.

Comment: @AliHassan Why do you think did I downvote you? I edited your question to fit the Stackoverflow guidelines, that's all. And btw. voting and closing is a form to keep this forum clean, it's not a method to punish you or any particular person.

Comment: ok sir thanks for your correction. but then why I have reduced by 8 points:(

Comment: @AliHassan Each person which downvotes your question reduces your score  by 2, an upvote increases your score by 5. You can see this in your Profile. You probably want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to get used to the StackOverflow habits;) For the future: Reread the [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) Page to increase your chance to get upvoted for a good question instead of earning a lot of downvotes for a poor question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery: `$("input[type='checkbox']").val('your value');`

Comment: Basically, I am getting the checkbox value through request object in node.js and there I am getting null/undefined. Now anybody can help me?

Code:
logger.info("checkbox value is: ",request.param('checkbox'));

output:
checkbox value is:  ''

login.ejs
function changeValue() {
var checkbox = document.forms["form1"].checkbox.value = "your value here";
}
<form id="form1" method="post" action="/login">
     
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="" /> Remember me<br />
     
</form>

Comment: No worries, pal. As always, the official jQuery website is always a good place to go. You watch, you learn :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 var checkbox = document.forms["form1"].checkbox.value = "your value here";
```

The JavaScript above will set "your value here" with this HTML:

```
 <form name="form1">
    <input name="checkbox" value="before change">
 </form>
```

Comment: It is not updating the value:(

Comment: The `name` attribute for `<form>` elements is long deprecated. Use `id` instead.

Comment: Oh you're right, I guess I have to stop being a grandpa about my 'name' attributes.  It's clear why it's deprecated, but unfortunately, I think it's going to cause confusion for newbies that realize FORM needs 'id' but INPUT needs 'name'

Answer (score 2):

The `value` property on an `HTMLInputElement` is read/write.

```
document.getElementById('myCheckbox').value = 'some value';
```

… although it is usually more useful to set the `checked` property to `true` or `false` unless you are creating new checkboxes.

---

> `var checkbox = document.getElementById(“form1”).getElementsByTagName(“checkbox”);`

This won't return a checkbox since:

1. `getElementsByTagName` returns a **NodeList** (which is like an array) not an **HTMLElement**. You have to loop over the results (or assume there will be only one and grab `[0]`).
2. The tag name for a checkbox is **input**

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" />bla bla

<script type="text/javascript">
var checkbox = document.getElementById('test');
checkbox.checked="checked";
</script>
```

Comment: Basically, I am getting the checkbox value through request object in node.js and there I am getting null/undefined. Now anybody can help me?

Code:
logger.info("checkbox value is: ",request.param('checkbox'));

output:
checkbox value is:  ''

login.ejs
function changeValue() {
var checkbox = document.forms["form1"].checkbox.value = "your value here";
}
<form id="form1" method="post" action="/login">
     
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="" /> Remember me<br />
     
</form>

Comment: Sry, dont know node.js. Was really assuming ´checked´ was in question, never encounted need for setting a checkbox value dynamically